# How to show/hide specific pages of an Access report?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm creating a per-employee report that will be output to PDF and some pages of the report will only be applicable to specific employees. Ideally I would like to not show those pages when the report is run or when it is output to PDF.

Each page of the report would be pulling from different data, so I was looking into sub-reports as a potential option.

The other thing that might complicate this is that I need to be able to perform a batch output of the report for multiple employees to individual PDF files.

What is the best way to go about achieving this? Sub reports that I show or hide based on the available data? I've searched pretty extensively and haven't found any suggestions on how best to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reportfields have a CanShrink Option. If its empty and nothing else is on that line horizontally it shrinks to nothing. If you set all fields of a page to CanShrink it disappears in Reports where all the fields of that page are empty.

Comment: Would that empty page still print or export to PDF even if it doesn't show when the report is viewed?

Comment: I have to fill 15 Chars just to say it: No

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for confirming for me. I'll try this out!